# regexp error on xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, regex, xslt-1.0, exslt

I am using xslt 1.0 to transform my xml.

I have this string:

```
hello 1s: This is very nice day. 9s: Christmas is about to come 14s: and christmas preparation is just on 25s: this is awesome!!
```

I want to format it like this:

```
hello This is very nice day. Christmas is about to come and christmas preparation is just on this is awesome!!
```

To do this, I tried this xslt:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
                extension-element-prefixes="regexp"  >
<xsl:import href="regexp.xsl" />
  <xsl:template match='/'>
         <xsl:value-of select="regexp:replace(string(.), '[0-9]{1,4}s: ', 'g', '')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I am getting the following error when i run that:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method java.lang.String.replace([ExpressionContext,] #STRING, #STRING, #STRING).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for regular expressions in XSLT 1.0. The EXSLT function you are calling is a third-party specification for extension functions that may be available in some processors; the error message you are getting suggests that it isn't available for your particular processor (or that you need to install/configure it somehow for that processor).

You're using Java, so there should be no obstacle to using XSLT 2.0 in the form of Saxon.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [fn:replace(string,pattern,replace)](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) itself. I dont know whether this is available in XSLT1.0 also; please check.

Examples for the string.replace function can be found [here](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_replace.html)

As per the documentation in the above link replace takes regex pattern.

> The fn:replace function replaces parts of a string that match a regular expression. The regular expression syntax used is defined by XML Schema with a few modifications/additions in XQueryXPath/XSLT. The $pattern argument is a regular expression. While it is nice to have the power of regular expressions, if you simply want to replace a particular sequence of characters you don't have to be familiar with regular expressions to do that; you can just specify the string you want replaced for $pattern, as long as it doesn't contain any special characters.

hence you can use fn:replace(text(), '[0-9]{1,4}s: ', '')

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.. but fn:replace fuction will replace fix text , but in my case.. my replace text is not fix (e. g , 1s: , 2s: , 3s: in this format ). so i have to apply regexp in it.. and i am running my xslt in linux server with solr search engine. so its giving error in this format.

Comment: The pattern in the replace function refers to regex pattern

Comment: hmm... i seen that.. but i don't have access of it in xslt 1.0

Comment: By any chance, are the source file and the regexp.xsl not in same directory or not in current directory?

Comment: @PragalathanM: `replace()` is an XPath 2.0 function and isn't available in XPath 1.0 (and in XSLT 1.0).

Comment: thanks all , for your help over this... i changed my xslt to work on 2.0